# How to check whether a document exists or not in cloud firestore for flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to check whether a document in the firestore exists or not using the snapshot, I am getting a red screen error returning null when I try to fetch a non existing document.

```
StreamBuilder(
              stream: Firestore.instance
                  .collection('Resumes')
                  .document(uid)
                  .snapshots(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                };
```

How do i check whether the document with name uid exists or not?

Comment: What is the error that you get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var res=Firestore.instance .collection('Resumes').documents;
if(res==null){
  print("no documents found");
}else{
  //there are documents
}
```

set the collection instance to a variable and check that if the variable is null or not using if statement.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [exists](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#exists()) method on the document snapshot to check whether the document exists or not:

```
DocumentSnapshot docSnapshot = await Firestore.instance.collection('Resumes').document(uid).get();
bool isDocExists = docSnapshot.exists(); //true if exists and false otherwise
```

Answer (score 2):

`snapshot.hasData` returns `true` even if the specified document does not exist in the collection.

To check if the document exists, you can check if `snapshot.data.data==null`

So, you'd have to change your code to:

```
StreamBuilder(
          stream: Firestore.instance
              .collection('Resumes')
              .document(uid)
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              if(snapshot.data.data==null){
                 
                 //document does not exist

              }
              else{

                 //document exists

              }


            } else{
               
              //Waiting for data 
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());

             }  
            };
```

Comment: To update this for null safe, use  

if(snapshot.data?.data() ==null. (or != null if you prefer to do positive cases first)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of document('uid')  do this:

```
 Firestore.instance .collection('Resumes').documents;
```

Then you can iterate through the documents checking for a match to the documentId property.

```
final document = snapshot.data.firstWhere((doc) => doc.documentId = uid, orElse: () => null)
```

Then, check if document != null